# How to implement an abstract class in F#?

Tags: f#, abstract-class

After I've seen [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/) PDC session I wanted to try to learn a bit of F#. So I thought the best way would be to rewrite in F# something I've already done in C# but my brain just refuses to think in functional mode. 
I have this abstract class that has some abstract methods and some virtual methods. I would like to override some of virtual methods as well. This class is written in C# and compiled and I don't intend to rewrite it i F#.
So my question is:

1. does anyone have a short sample of how to implement  an abstract class, abstract method and virtual method
2. can I have overloaded constructors?
3. are there any constraints if I want to compile it in a dll and make it available to my C# based programs.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update:
I really really appreciated Brian's answer but it is still not clear to me so I want to clarify. Let's pretend this is my abstract class written in C# and compiled in dll. How do I implement it in F#?

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public abstract Person GetFullName(string firstName, string lastName);

    public abstract bool TryParse(string fullName, out Person person);

    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> GetChildren(Person parent)
    {
        List<Person> kids = new List<Person>();
        foreach(Child person in GroupOfPeople)
        {
            if(person.Parent == parent)
               kids.Add(child as Person);
        }
        return kids;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> GroupOfPeople { get; set; }
}
```

---

Some documentation for whomever is looking for some F# resources:
  - if any other F# is interested to get some documentation I found on Don Syme's (creator of F#) blog [free chapters of his book F# Expert](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2006/12/18/DraftChaptersUpdateDec2006.aspx). You can download those in doc format.

- Real World Functional Programming by Tomas Petricek has  [free chapter here](http://www.manning.com/petricek/petricek_meapch1.pdf)

Some other resources that might of interest:

- [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode34TheRiseOfF.aspx) post
- [Dustin Campbell's blog](http://diditwith.net/default.aspx)
- [Tomas Petricek's blog](http://tomasp.net/blog/)
- The place for F# - [hubFS](http://cs.hubfs.net/)
- [F# WIKI](http://www.strangelights.com/fsharp/wiki/default.aspx/FSharpWiki/HomePage.html)
- [Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/community.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's some sample code

```
type IBaz =
    abstract member Baz : int -> int

[<AbstractClass>]
type MyAbsClass() =
    // abstract
    abstract member Foo : int -> int
    // virtual (abstract with default value)
    abstract member Bar : string -> int
    default this.Bar s = s.Length 
    // concrete
    member this.Qux x = x + 1

    // a way to implement an interface
    abstract member Baz: int -> int
    interface IBaz with
        member this.Baz x = this.Baz x

type MySubClass(z : int) =
    inherit MyAbsClass()
    override this.Foo x = x + 2
    override this.Bar s = (base.Bar s) - 1
    override this.Baz x = x + 100
    member this.Z = z
    new () = MySubClass(0)

let c = new MySubClass(42)    
printfn "%d %d %d %d %d" c.Z (c.Foo 40) (c.Bar "two") (c.Qux 41) (c.Baz 42000)
```

Comment: Is it possible for an F# abstract class to implement an interface too ?

Comment: Actualy I meaned is it possible to have abstract member that interface  an interface. E.g.
interface IBaz with
        abstract member Baz : int -> int

Comment: No, that syntax is not allowed, as it'd be rougly equivalent to "abstract class C : System.IComparable { abstract int System.IComparable.CompareTo(object x); }" in C#, which is also not allowed.